# Abstract class and methods

Tags: oop

i have Abstract class

```
Public class Abstract baseClass
{
     public abstract string GetString();
     public abstract string GetString1();
}

public class DerivedClass : baseClass
{
      public override string GetString()
        {
            return "test data";
        }

    public override string GetString1()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In above line of code, i have to implement both abstract method in derived class. But due to some reason i don't want to implement all methods, just one of them like GetString() only. How can it be done?

Thanks

Comment: Why? Clearly the derivedClass inherits all the features from `baseClass` so it should implement _all the features_ from `baseClass`. Split `baseClass` into two classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `DerivedClass` is going to offer common functionality to other classes, you can mark it as abstract, implement one of the methods here, and then inheritors will only have to implement the remaining method.

If you aren't going to support the other method in a given implementation, you still have to expose the method in your class, but similar to what you have here, you would typically throw a `NotSupportedException`. For `void` methods, you could simply return (do nothing).

Finally, if you want to separate out the things that have both methods and those that have only one, you can use interfaces.

```
public interface IBase
{
    string GetString();
}

public interface IBasePlus : IBase
{
    string GetStringPlus();
}
```

You can have one class that implements `IBasePlus`, but you can supply this to methods that take a parameter of type `IBase`, in which case you won't see the extra method.

Comment: thanks for revert jay,,, i got ur point. actually i was just trying to sort out that is there any keyword or any default functionality available on OOPs. Means like virtual methods are not necessary needed to implement in derived class. In the same way,, can we do some thing like this with abstract method?

Comment: @Amit You can have default functionality in the abstract class by declaring a member `virtual`, and that default functionality may be to do nothing. Then you only override & implement it in derived classes if you need it; it isn't required.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if you don't implement all the abstract methods then your new class is also an abstract class. To get a concrete class, you need all the methods to be implemented. If you only want/need to implement a subset of the methods, consider using multiple interfaces (one interface with GetString and another with GetString1) rather than an abstract class. Then you can just implement the interfaces with the methods you want to use in the class.

Comment: Thanks for revert todd. i like ur idea

Comment: Plus 1 for multiple interfaces. Consider also [how Java Collections handle unsupported (or unimplemented) methods](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UnsupportedOperationException).

Answer (score 0):

Take the abstract keyword off the other method and provide a default implementation in the base class

Comment: but i have to give signature only in base class due to some scenario.